# How do I tether my android tablet to my Huawei U2801-34 phone

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, reverse-tether

I have a Hipstreet Flare 3 Model# HS-9DTB37-8GB, and I'm wondering if there is a way to tether it to my Huawei U2801-34 phone. It's not a smart phone, so it will most likely need me to install drivers to my tablet, but I'm not sure where I would look to find them, if they exist. I am able to tether it to my PC using The Huawei assistant software that the phone installs on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Install shareIt app on both devices and the phone will do a hotspot tether with the tablet. SnapShare and SFT apps also perform hotspot tether. If you are doing file transfers the Snapshare does fastest with simultaneous dl's.

Comment: Could you link the apps here?